# Use Mule Data Mapper to enrich an existing payload

Tags: mule

i have a Mule flow that gathers calculations information from an external service to enrich a list of Invoices. So, I end up (after the enricher scope) with my calc info in a flow variable, and my original invoices in the payload.

Can I use the data mapper to inject my calculation values into the existing invoice objects?

Currently I'm using a Groovy script - but prefer config over scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the datamapper transformer within an enricher scope to enrich parts of the payload.

The enricher can enrich the payload if you set the 'target' to a named field on a POJO for example, or if your payload is a Map, the enricher will add a new entry to the Map.

```
<enricher>
   <datamapper... />
   <enrich target="#[payload.field1]" source="#[payload.datamapperoutputfield1]" />
   <enrich target="#[payload.field2]" source="#[payload.datamapperoutputfield1]" />
</enricher>
```

Comment: Love the way to enrich the payload - was looking for that in another case. Using your technique with datamapper though, seems like double work.